# SELECT con multiples columnas de tablas - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

tengo el siguiente codigo funcional

```
 return $this->select("SELECT  ORD.order_id,ORD.date_created,ORD.num_items_sold,ORD.total_sales
     FROM wpsz_wc_order_stats ORD
     join wpsz_wc_customer_lookup CLI 
        on CLI.customer_id = ORD.customer_id
     join wpsz_postmeta DEPTO 
        on DEPTO.post_id = ORD.order_id 
        and DEPTO.meta_key = '_shipping_country'
    join wpsz_postmeta LOCALI 
        on LOCALI.post_id = ORD.order_id
        and LOCALI.meta_key = '_shipping_state'
    join ges_interna_mapeo_sucursales MAPEO
        on MAPEO.idPaisWooCommerce = DEPTO.meta_value 
        and MAPEO.idLocalidadWooCommerce = LOCALI.meta_value            
    order by date_created ASC ;");
```

el mismo me trae la info

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al intentar agregarle mas datos en el select de las otras tablas joineadas no me da error pero no me trae nada ejemplo "CLI.FIRSTNAME"
ej:

```
    return $this->select("SELECT  ORD.order_id,ORD.date_created,ORD.num_items_sold,ORD.total_sales,CLI.first_name
     FROM wpsz_wc_order_stats ORD
     join wpsz_wc_customer_lookup CLI 
        on CLI.customer_id = ORD.customer_id
     join wpsz_postmeta DEPTO 
        on DEPTO.post_id = ORD.order_id 
        and DEPTO.meta_key = '_shipping_country'
    join wpsz_postmeta LOCALI 
        on LOCALI.post_id = ORD.order_id
        and LOCALI.meta_key = '_shipping_state'
    join ges_interna_mapeo_sucursales MAPEO
        on MAPEO.idPaisWooCommerce = DEPTO.meta_value 
        and MAPEO.idLocalidadWooCommerce = LOCALI.meta_value            
    order by date_created ASC ;");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

probe la consulta directamente por mysql y si trae datos,

dejo metodos usados

```
public function select($query = "" , $types = [], $values = [])
{
    try {
        $stmt = $this->executeStatement( $query , $types , $values);
        $result = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);             
        $stmt->close();

        return $result;
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        throw New Exception( $e->getMessage() );
    }
    return false;
}


private function executeStatement($query = "" , $types = [], $values = [])
{
    try {
        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare( $query );

        if($stmt === false) {
            throw New Exception("Unable to do prepared statement: " . $query);
        }

        if( $values ) {                 
            $values = array_values($values);
            $stmt->bind_param($types[0], ...$values);
        }

        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt;
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        throw New Exception( $e->getMessage() );
    }   
}
```

Comment: Convendría que hagas de algún modo una depuración del resultado. En la pregunta no queda claro si emites un JSON, parece que sí... pues bien, ese JSON podría estar siendo inválido, por problemas de codificación u otros. Depura lo que devuelve la consulta SQL y dinos el resultado de esa depuración.

Comment: Yo uso Visual Studio Code, y tengo un xamp.. como me recomiendas depurar?, disculpa la ignorancia

Comment: No uso ni uno ni otro, e ignoro qué métodos tengan para depurar (algunos IDE permiten poner puntos de interrupción en el código y examinar el valor de las variables en cada punto ... seria lo ideal). O, la depuración en bruto de PHP con `var_dump($loQueQuieresDepurar);` Así verás lo que hay como resultado de la consulta SQL por ejemplo. También, convendría que nos digas si mandas eso como respuesta en forma de JSON por ejemplo y que muestres el código que convierte la respuesta a JSON.